# I cannot understand this code

Tags: c++, c, linux, g++

I've been given a C/C++ code that looks like this:

```
extern int ZEXPORT zipOpenNewFileInZip3 (file, filename, zipfi, extrafield_local)
  zipFile file;
  const char* filename;
  const zip_fileinfo* zipfi;
  const void* extrafield_local;

{

... function body

}
```

Is declaring the parameters of a function like that possible? I'm getting errors from the compiler (g++).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possbible and known as K&R style.

Comment: This isn't C/C++. That isn't a language. This is old C.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases

Comment: You're not the same guy as asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566422/what-is-the-weird-usage-in-c-language) are you? Either way, see [these related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566422/what-is-the-weird-usage-in-c-language#comment25556566_17566422).

Comment: Old (and obsolescent) style, don't use it

Comment: WOW! I don't know how many years it is, since I last have seen or used this kind of function declarations. Must be more than 20 Years or so, and now it looks so wrong. :) Those were the days...

Comment: I've compiled using -std=C89 and it works like a charm.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: `zlib` is full of such declarations, I was also surprised by that quite recently.

Comment: I borrowed an old C book some two years ago , it was probably ANSI standard . I read this kind of declaration in that book. Nostalgia :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old-school C (pre-ANSI C syntax) way for doing things. I suggest you change it, if you own the code, to

```
extern int ZEXPORT zipOpenNewFileInZip3 (
  zipFile file,
  const char* filename,
  const zip_fileinfo* zipfi,
  const void* extrafield_local)
...
```

There are some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602002/confused-over-function-call-in-pre-ansi-c-syntax) and [here](http://www.9wy.net/onlinebook/CPrimerPlus5/ch09lev1sec2.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is ancient syntax for defining functions in C. It predates the first standardized version of the C language. More importantly, that syntax has never been valid C++. Since you are compiling this code (which is obviously C code) with a C++ compiler, it is failing.